# Using puppeteer to screenshot local files, but it's still making web requests?

Tags: caching, puppeteer, headless

I am using Puppeteer to take screenshots of a web page for my company. I need to test multiple people's accounts so that means visiting the page multiple times (150 times in this case). This results in our firewall kicking me out for making too many requests.

My solution is to just fetch the contents of the page and save them locally. Then I use puppeteer on that local file, overriding the function used to get data from our servers to instead just use data already loaded into Node from a CSV.

All of this works, but it looks like it's still making requests to our servers.

I tried giving it a `userDataDir` so it could cache any resources. In theory, if it's loading it from `file://`, it's caching the resources and there's no Ajax requests, it shouldn't be making any further requests, right?

I also tried installing a debugging proxy but since it's https I can't see what it's trying to request.

This is how I start it:

```js
puppeteer.launch({
    userDataDir: "temp/"
})
.then(browser => {
    next(browser, links);
)
.catch(error => {
    cb(error, null);
});
```

`next` will iterate through any links it needs to visit.

This part saves the page locally:

```js
if (this._linkCache[baseLink] === undefined) {

    fetch(baseLink)
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(contents => {

            fs.writeFile(fullFileName, contents, 'utf8', err => {
                if (err) {
                    cb(err, null);
                } else {
                    this._linkCache[baseLink] = fileUrl;

                    gotoPage(fileUrl);
                }
            });

        })
        .catch(error => {
            cb(error, null);
        });
}

// Go to the cached version
else {
    gotoPage(this._linkCache[baseLink] + queryParams);
}
```

And this gets the screenshots:

```js
const gotoPage = async(url) => {
    try {
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        // Override 'fetchAccountData' function
        await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(testData => {
            window["fetchAccountData"] = (cb: (err: any, data: any)=>void) => {
                cb(null, testData);
            };
        }, data);

        // Go to page and get screenshot
        await page.goto(url);
        const screenie = `${outputPath}${uuid()}.png`;
        await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true, path: screenie, type: "png" });

        pageHtml.push(`<img src="file://${screenie}" />`);

        next(browser, rest);

    } catch (e) {
        cb(e, null);
    }
};
```

I was hoping this would be able to only make a few requests at the beginning while it saves the html locally and caches all the resources, but it seems to make a request for every link.

How can I stop it?

Comment: you cant login into a website from localhost if thats what you mean thats not how it works .... you need to get a proxy list and send your requests with different ips using those proxies so you wont get blocked .. also you may need to clear your cookies for each account

Comment: I'm not trying to log in, I'm just trying to get a screenshot of the page. The page is populated with account data but I've tricked it into not making a server request when getting the screenshots. In other words I have all the HTML, JS and data that I need to do it all locally without ever having to make any web requests, but it's still doing them and I'm trying to find out what I'm missing.

Comment: well if you have all the files in your pc and can load the pages locally , just disconnect your pc from internet

Comment: The files first have to be downloaded during while the program is running. I tried disconnecting but it's still trying to make web requests. I'm trying to understand why it's making web requests when a) the html/js/css is stored locally, b) the ajax requests are removed and it's loading data locally and c) puppeteer is caching the resources it gets. I know it's making requests because I can see them using a proxy, but since it's https I can't tell what it's trying to load. If I can find out why it's still trying to make requests I might get closer to a solution.